# MonoForAndroid MainLauncher

Tags: android, mono, launcher

I am developing apps with MonoForAndroid.I do not want an icon for my app.I set Attribute like this,but my app showed up in Android's application launcher screen.

```
[Activity]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionMain })]
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
}
```